# Do I have to load the csv values into a DB for java web app

Tags: java, jsp, csv

I'm looking to make a web that makes use of two sets of databases, given in CSV format and both are 10 MB in size. I've chosen to use Java dynamic web app with JSP, that users can use to search and sort through the data provided through the CSV.

From what I understand, the user/client sends a request to the server, the server will call upon the Java cases in the backend, which has the different sorting methods and data from the CSV that can be manipulated.

This data, that sits in the backend, is where I'm running into confusion. I know its possible to load the data to a database, and have that sitting on the server that I could call upon.

If I use a class that reads the CSV and loads the data to arrays, Would this reading work be done every time someone accesses the website causing latency or would it already be loaded into arrays in the server?

Comment: But since its a Web app reading csv file into array and storing in session may consume space and If this have to be accessed your several clients it may crash or slow sown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the scope you use it would be loaded in an application context, therefore one time (say in a singleton class loaded at the application startup).

But I wouldn't recommend this approach, I would recommend a proper designed database where you can put your csv data into. This way you would have the database engine to help you organize your data which would give you scalability and maintainability (although with a proper design of your classes say a DAO pattern would give you the same). 
Organized data in a database would give you more flexibility to search through your data using already made SQL functions.

In order to make my case here are some advantages of a Database system over a file system:

- No redundant data – Redundancy removed by data normalization
- Data Consistency and Integrity – data normalization takes care of it too
- Secure – Each user has a different set of access
- Privacy – Limited access
- Easy access to data
- Easy recovery
- Flexible
- Concurrency - The database engine will allow you to concurrent read the data or even write to it.

I'm not listing the disadvantages since I'm making my case :)

Comment: I'll be using my own implemented sorting algorithms to search and sort the data. For this reason do you think it would be easier use DOA patters.

Comment: Even with your own implemented sorting algorithms it would be good to use a pattern like DAO because it would separate the responsibility of the application business layer and the data layer. That would give you the flexibility to (if you want)  in the future change your way of access the data from database, file system or whatever without having to make big changes into the system. Read about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object

Comment: Can i use my own methods to search through the data instead of SQL functions if i uploaded my csv to the db? Also with a DAO approach, its possible i could use this singleton class at application start up can read the csv and store the data in a DAO pattern for use by the application? will this function be run everytime someone access the web application or just when i start up/run the application.

Comment: 1 - If you upload your data to a SQL database you wouldn't need your methods but you could still use it, although you would be reinventing the wheel or doing the job twice. I'm not saying that your algorithms is bad, just that the database are well know and widely used throughout the entire world if you still think that your algorithms is better I would strongly advice you in trying to sell then :) ! 2 - Yes it would be possible, the DAO pattern and the Class to load the data using a [Singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) are two approaches that can be used....

Comment: Togheter. It would depend on what technologies you would be using on your project. You don't store the data in a DAO pattern, it is an application layer, a design to a better separation of responsibilities of your application. Your data would be stored on the csv files and loaded into classes to be used by the your implementation of the DAO pattern. 3 - This was already answered, if it is an application scope and using a singleton pattern it would be loaded just when the server starts up.

Answer (score 0):

I can read from a CSV file to build your arrays.  You can then add the arrays to session scope.  The CSV file will only be read at the servlet that processes it.  Future usage will be retrieved from session.